# How can I avoid unnecessary sequence increment on "INSERT [...] ON CONFLICT [...]" in Postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.5

It appears that as soon as the `INSERT` clause is run, my sequence values increment, and are not rolled back to the previous number. Is there any way to avoid incrementing the sequence number?

I am trying to populate a table from a CSV, inserting rows where they haven't yet been added and doing nothing except returning the ID if they have already been added (there may well be a better way to do this):

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO development_status (dst_name) VALUES (%s) ON CONFLICT (dst_name) DO UPDATE SET dst_name = %s RETURNING dst_id;", (status,status,))
        id_of_status = cur.fetchone()[0]
 if len(development_site) > 0:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO development_site (ds_name,ds_developer,ds_zone,ds_status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) ON CONFLICT (ds_name) DO UPDATE SET ds_name = %s RETURNING ds_id;", (development_site,id_of_developer,zone,id_of_status,development_site,))
        id_of_site = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: Yes: create a temp table , insert the csv into thuis temp, and do a `insert into target(...) select ... from temp where not exists (...);`

Comment: This seems to be expected behaviour: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAM3SWZQMfR6Zfe3A0Nr4ddko8xZrijAuQQ=EcGjGeJSs2piAXA@mail.gmail.com

Comment: Yes of course it is. A gapless sequence would cause a locking bottleneck / nightmare.